# Suitable exact optimization method

Tags: optimization

I am looking for a suitable (exact) optimization method for the following problem (I have already solved the same problem using heuristic methods).

For *j* number of **binary** variables (i.e.: $x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_j$), a variable *A* is defined as follows:

$A=\sum\limits_{i=1}^j x_i$.

Furthermore, there's *B*:

$B=f(x_j)$,

a **non-linear** function of all values $x_1 ... x_j$. (i.e.: how much $x_a$ increases $B$, depends on the values of all other $x_j$).

Now I want to achieve the following:

$min(A-B)$

Is it possible to capture this in a MILP / MINLP problem? Any hints or pointers are much appreciated! I am thinking the non-linear part in the objective function prevents me from using some form of LP, and/or makes it much more complex, but I can't seem to figure out why, let alone prove it. (I am not a mathematician by training :(..)

Thanks!

Comment: what is the formula for $f$?

Comment: So far, I have only been able to put that in a table. To explain the problem a little more:


|| _j_ number of stations in a plant can be automated
|| the more plants are automated, the faster the total process, the higher _B_ (= cost reduction)
|| the more plants are automated, the higher the total investment costs (_A_)
|| speeding up the process by adding automated stations is interdependent, e.g. the added performance (incease of _B_) per new automated station depends on the number _and_ location of existing automated stations. ||

I am working on defining/finding $f$ right now.

Comment: Furthermore, I'd like to add that $f$ is not either constantly increasing or decreasing, it's more or less all over the place while gradually adding more automated stations, and/or moving automated stations 'down the production line'.

I.e. 2 out 6 automated might give a nice performance, while 3 out 6 might perform worse, and 4 out 6 better again. Also putting the 2 stations in location 1 and 3 may perform better than in 1 and 4, or 1 and 2.

Comment: If you can only put those numbers in a table and can't give any general properties, how could any algorithm find the optimum without enumerating all options?

Comment: Let's assume I can't find $f$ (to be a continuous function), that would mean there's no way to solve this with an exact optimization method? Perhaps except by breaking it up in (many small) sub-problems?